# function of LPE folder android on android 6+ and tmp .raw files

Tags: android

There is a folder named LPE on device storage of androids 6+. Google does not know the answer, you might.

Does anybody has an idea what it does and how it does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LPE folder is used by Samsung's Camera and Photo Editor apps. The files inside are photos in a raw format. If you open the file in photoshop, you can make out the image somewhat. The specifics of the image bit orders are not known.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of interesting to see the paranoia of people.

I will tell you the result.

The folder comes if you install a watch app and use a watch.

Thats it. Not more or less.

Tracked it exactly, the date when using a new Samsung 6 Watch and while installing Samsung GALAXY WEARABLE.

Started to use specific images for the clock design/mockup.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but if. LPE folder is used by Samsung's Camera and Photo Editor apps. .why I just.

Get it after 2 years...of using my mobile...
I tell how you get it and more

I record strange  action from some sites...

After 1st visit I get 4 folders..date is same date and time I was on those sites....

The are some government sites....in ..and coulld  be in some other gov.other countries....

It's making  screen shot to your screen...
In raw files ....

Folders mask_airemover. And airemover
And   portrait.  And  LPE.....

Any to act like camera .app and editing....
It's not.....

It's

Something  no one talked  about.....qz.no one knows where to go....

It's high level gov.spying..Tech....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSrlQ.png)

Comment: Please refrain from posting irrelevant and unnecessary answers. It's a waste of other's time looking for an answer and not at all in line with the Platform's guideline. This is not a place to make conspiracy theories.